# Reusing a returned custom object in Python-xlwings

Tags: python, excel, interactive, xlwings

The question is rather conceptual: when using xlwings and UDFs, python functions are called from Excel and the return value is returned to Excel.

Now consider a function that gets some input from the Excel, its return value is a custom object and this return value should be used in many subsequent calculations that are to be shown in the Excel sheet.

Is it possible to make use of this returned custom object in a subsequent Excel call or are the displayed results kind of an "end of the road" if not a built in variable is returned?

By accessing I mean either using it as an input variable for a subsequent Excel call (as a cell address), or as a variable that is stored in the pyhon script before returning anything so it can be accessed within the python script paired with the excel sheet.

I hope my question is clear but AMA if not.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python (actually if I'm being honest, I'm not at all familiar with python..) but can you not save the object in Excel? So when Excel receives the object, it can save the details in a hidden sheet or hidden column? or have I completely misunderstood the question?

Comment: The object that is returned is converted to some COM type for displaying, but as it is an _object_ that is returned, it should be accessible somehow, but probably not as directly is I hope.

Comment: Assuming that xlwings/Python allows for Global or Static objects your UDF could return a unique identifier handle for the object to the cell, and other Python UDFs could be passed the cell containing the identifier handle and access the static object. Note: handling persistence of the objects would be more complex.

Comment: I _think_ I understand what you mean. Good idea, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Just a short recap @CharlesWilliams: using a global variable in the .py file associated with the UDFs to maintain the model state works, but then you get problems with the cell execution order of Excel. And at that point I gave up trying and switched to wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem a long time ago.

In the code below `@xw.arg('x', ExcelVar)` means that the argument named `x` corresponding to a variable name previously returned in Excel by another function will be replaced by what is stored in the `var_values` static dictionary before the body of the function executes. So then it means that you can use the same functions in Python or Excel. In Python pass any object, in Excel pass a variable name.

This is very useful, it could maybe even be included in the xlwings library, I haven't followed though if anybody did something similar or not.

```
# excel wings functions for reading an object in excel, can be uncommented if needed
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.conversion import Converter

#http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html
class ExcelVar(Converter):
    var_names = {}
    var_values = {}

    #CRUD methods (create, read, update, delete)
    @staticmethod
    def write_value(value, options):
        var_name = options.get('name', 'var')
           
        if var_name in ExcelVar.var_names:
            ExcelVar.var_names[var_name] += 1
        else:
            ExcelVar.var_names[var_name] = 0

        used_var_name = f"{var_name}${ExcelVar.var_names[var_name]}"
        ExcelVar.var_values[used_var_name] = value

        return used_var_name

    @staticmethod
    def read_value(var_name, options):
        #allows to pass a variable string name or a value directly from Excel
        if not isinstance(var_name, str):
            return 'ExcelVar needs to be a string'
            
        if var_name not in ExcelVar.var_values:
            return f"{var_name} undefined"
                
        return ExcelVar.var_values[var_name]

    @staticmethod
    def update_value(var_name, value):
        ExcelVar.var_values[var_name] = value
        
        return var_name

    @staticmethod
    def delete_value(var_name):
        if var_name not in ExcelVar.var_values:
            return f"{var_name} undefined"
            
        del ExcelVar.var_values[var_name]
        
        return f"{var_name} deleted"

    @staticmethod
    def var_exists(var_name):
        return var_name in ExcelVar.var_values

#helper functions to be used in Excel or in python code
@xw.func
def create_excel_var(var_name, value):
    #returns an incremented variable like in excel
    return ExcelVar.write_value(value, dict(name=var_name))

@xw.func
def read_excel_var(var_name):
    return ExcelVar.read_value(var_name, {})

@xw.func
def update_excel_var(var_name, value):
    #updates or writes a new non incremented variable
    return ExcelVar.update_value(var_name, value)

@xw.func
def delete_excel_var(var_name):
    return ExcelVar.delete_value(var_name)

@xw.func
def excel_var_exists(var_name):
    return ExcelVar.var_exists(var_name)
   
#practical examples of ExcelVar for excel
@xw.func 
@xw.ret(ExcelVar, name='test_var')
def test_excel_var(x):
    return x + 1

@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', ExcelVar)
def test_read_excel_var(x):
    return x
```